# FishPig Wordpress Integration Magento extension

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I am using FishPig Wordpress Integration extension and its working fine. Question is, when I type in Magento Default searchbar on the homepage, I want it to pull back the results from products, CMS pages and blog posts. By default it pulls back the products. For CMS pages search, I have installed Tangkoko CmsSearch extension and this also works perfectly. The only thing I am stuck with is, searching blog posts. Is there any way that I can achieve this as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into google custom search. While this may not be exactly what you are looking for you can choose to index parts of your site such as domain.com/blog, domain.com/products, domain.com/pages.

Here is an article about how to add it into magento.
http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/2012/07/09/how-to-add-google-custom-search-into-magento/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use the Integrated Search extension from Fishpig, the same developers.
You can find it here: http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/integrated-search/